# Simple boost smart pointer syntax issue

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

When using either `boost::scoped_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` I get the error

> 1>***\algomanager.cpp(28) : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a
>   function taking 1 arguments

I have code like this . . .

```
class X{
  boost::shared_ptr<cPreFilterProcess> preProcess;
public:
  X(){
    preProcess(new cPreFilterProcess(pars));
  }
};
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Show the complete constructor of the class.

Comment: You're saying this: `boost::shared_ptr<cPreFilterProcess> preProcess(new ....)` doesn't work?

Comment: `boost::shared_ptr<cPreFilterProcess>  preProcess ( new cPreFilterProcess(pars) );` does work, but I want `preProcess` to be in the class definition, so that it is tied to the lifetime of the owning object.

Comment: You probably should have shown a complete code example then, so people wouldn't have to guess what you meant and Xeo wouldn't have to wear out the batteries on the mythical glass orb of magic debugging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My mythical glass orb of magic debugging tells me you're doing something like this:

```
class X{
  boost::shared_ptr<cPreFilterProcess> preProcess;
public:
  X(){
    preProcess(new cPreFilterProcess(pars));
  }
};
```

You need to use either the member initializer like:

```
X() : preProcess(...){}
```

Or use `.reset` since your can't just assign a pointer like that:

```
X() { preProcess.reset(...); }
```

I would strongly recommend the first option though.

Comment: That is a powerful orb! I have updated my question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Great, both of these work. Why is the first option more strongly recommended?

Comment: @learnvst: Because the second option is basically `X() : preProcess() { preProcess.reset(...); }`, that is, it default initializes and then resets the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: So the first option prevents a wasted initialization?

Comment: @learnvst: Correct. You can search SO, there are a few topics on that.

Answer (score 3):

If you just write this as a statement:

```
preProcess ( new cPreFilterProcess(pars) );
```

it's not valid, because `preProcess` is already constructed, so that syntax tries to "call" it like a function.

This is not valid either:

```
preProcess = new cPreFilterProcess(pars);
```

because you can't assign a `cPreFilterProcess*` to a `shared_ptr<cPreFilterProcess>`

Maybe you mean:

```
preProcess.reset( new cPreFilterProcess(pars) );
```

or

```
preProcess = boost::shared_ptr<cPreFilterProcess>( new cPreFilterProcess(pars) );
```